# Wget on Linux saves files differently if called from the command line vs running from a script

Tags: shell, wget, naming

I use wget to download a file to my server.

When I paste this in the terminal command line : wget 'https://www.example.com/export/komatsu/komatsu_export.php?pass=Kowa444m11008&date=month' -O /root/workingdir/KOWA_SampleResult_ZAF_`date +"%Y%m%d"`.csv

it saves the file as KOWA_SampleResult_ZAF_20221215.csv

But when I paste the same line into a .sh file and run the file e.g. sh kowa_automate.sh

it saves the file as 'KOWA_SampleResult_ZAF_20221215.csv'$'\r'

Why the discrepancy with the extra symbols : '  '$'\r'

Andrew

I tried running the script bash kowa_automate.sh.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that Linux interprets Windows created text files differently. Windows new lines include CR LF, whereas Linux only uses LF. Hence the \r.

If in a text editor such as notepad++ on windows; you must use the EOL conversion to Unix.